# How to ignore node_modules from prettier

Tags: javascript, lint, prettier

**Using pretty-quick for beautification purpose**

Prettier configuration and Eslint rules are affecting the node_modules. So, want to skip it.

Hence, tried creating .prettierignore file having node_modules defined inside it

Have config setup rule like this below:

```
"lint": "pretty-quick & eslint "src/**/*.{js,jsx}" --quiet --fix"
```

Giving error as:

```
SyntaxError: Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings (8:9)
  6 | artifact: 'file://dcs.tar.gz'
  7 | deploymentStrategy: default
> 8 | config: artifact:
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 9 |
    | ^
    at e (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/parser-yaml.js:1:323)
    at Object.parse (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/parser-yaml.js:1:156977)
    at Object.parse$2 [as parse] (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/index.js:7138:19)
    at coreFormat (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/index.js:10398:23)
    at format (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/index.js:10570:16)
    at formatWithCursor (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/index.js:10582:12)
    at /Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/index.js:34924:15
    at format (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/prettier/index.js:34943:12)
    at exports.default (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/pretty-quick/dist/formatFiles.js:18:41)
    at exports.default (/Users/mithha/Documents/dcs/ui/ui-plugins/dcs/node_modules/pretty-quick/dist/index.js:54:29)
✨  Done in 4.19s.
```

Also tried configuring like this:

```
"lint": "pretty-quick --ignore-path=.prettierignore & eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet --fix"
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must only do the changes for staged files by passing `--staged` to the existing command as shown below is the only solution i came up for now to move on.

```
"lint": "pretty-quick --staged & eslint "src/**/*.{js,jsx}" --quiet --fix"
```

Answer (score 40):

Prettier's CLI ignores node_modules by default.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#--with-node-modules

Comment: not in webstorm

Answer (score 2):

According the npm package description, prettier ignores the files you wrote a path in `.prettierrc`, `.prettierignore`, and `.editorconfig`.

You're gonna check it out below if you wanna know more.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-quick#configuration-and-ignore-files

Comment: It’s not working, that’s the reason posting it with error

Comment: Did you try to insert the path to all patterns?

Answer (score 1):

in the `.eslintignore` file, add the following line:

```
/node_modules/
```

Comment: Add those lines of the options object to the webpack.base.conf.js file

`module: {
    rules: [
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
          emitWarning: true
        },
    ...
`

Comment: we dont have webpack configured. is there any possibility to handle it inside `.eslintrc` ?

Comment: try this lines in console: `npm i -g eslint` 
`eslint --ignore-path .gitignore node_modules/*`

Comment: `npm ERR! Could not install ".gitignore" as it is not a directory and is not a file with a name ending in .tgz, .tar.gz or .tar`

Comment: or `eslint --ignore-path node_modules/*`

Comment: i have eslintignore which is working perfectly fine, but prettier has issues

Comment: @Mithun The commands posted by @javimovi were two separate commands; the first was to install eslint globally (`npm i -g eslint`) while the second was to run this globally installed eslint with parameters to say which files to ignore (`eslint --ignore-path .gitignore node_modules/*`). Note what you might also need to install other eslint dependencies globally as well for this to work.